# updating partial view mvc from other partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two partial views, one for `SEARCH` and one for `SEARCHRESULTS`.

I want to update `SEARCHRESULTS` when the "Search" button is clicked on the `SEARCH` partial view form.

`SEARCHRESULTS` needs to have the form data fed to it from the `SEARCH` partial view.

I'm not totally sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AJAX Form and initially load the SEARCH partial view into a div. Then setup the ajax form to post to your controller and then have that controller action return the SEARCHRESULTS partial. The controller action should have a Model tied to it that will have the SAERCHRESULTS form values in it.

Something like should work in your view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "targetDiv" }))
{

}
```